# How many different equations of a circle are there?

Tags: circles

$$\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}=cst$$ reduces to the equation of a circle: $x^2+y^2=2$

How many other equations reduce to circles?

Comment: Someone surprised you with a problem that you had not seen, and now to prevent that you are planing to memorize the list?

Comment: If your $cst=\frac15$ then the point $(2,0)$ satisfies your original equation but not $x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many ways for equations to be reducible (what ever that really is) to the equation of a circle. You circle is not **a** circle it is the specific case of the unit circle at the origin.